# Updating a column based on another column + interval

Tags: mysql

Our database currently has a course_start_date, but not a course_end_date. My goal is to set each course _end_date based on course_start_date + 3 days based on course_type_id. course_start_date is currently stored as a unix_timestamp. Here is my code.

```
UPDATE system_course 
SET course_end_date = 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(course_start_date), INTERVAL 3 DAY))' 
WHERE course_type_id = '1'
```

This code is placing 0 in everything.

```
Both course_start_date and course_end_date are structured:

INT(11) unassigned
```

Running the following code shows me good results (obviously End Date is not stored in the db)

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(course_start_date) as "Start Date", DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(course_start_date), INTERVAL 4 DAY) as "End Date" 
FROM system_course
WHERE course_type_id = '1'
```

Select Results:

```
Start Date             End Date
2011-10-31 07:30:00    2011-11-03 07:30:00
```

Can I not use row parameters in the set column? How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is in single quotes, this will treat it as a string and cast to zero as demonstrated. What you want is this;

```
SET course_end_date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(FROM_UN...
```